# Using C# Method in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, methods

**My aspx page:**

```
<asp:TableCell>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbFirstName" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onblur="javascript:CheckFirstNameInput(this)"> 
        </asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
```

**My C# class**

```
[ScriptService()]
public static class InputChecks
{
[WebMethod()]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public static bool CheckForLettersSpacesStripes(string input)
    {  //SomeCode   }}
```

**My masterpage**

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="smScriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true">
    <Scripts>
    <!-- And some standard imported scripts -->
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Resources/JavaScriptFunctions.js" />

    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

As you might notice, the idea is that I import a javascript here, which works fine. Tested it out with an alert and several console.logs and stuff. But I can't reach the C# methods, I used several stuff. I used an ajax call:

```
    function CheckFirstNameInput(InputElement)
{
    var Input = InputElement.value;
    console.log(Input);
    $.ajax({
        url: "Test",
        data: "{input : " + Input + "}",
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response.url);
        }
    });
}
```

But also I just used PageMethods. None of the above worked, I tried placing the scriptmanager in the aspx page instead of the masterpages, didn't work out. I am completely out of ideas, and I am not finding any new stuff on the net. So, is there anyone who knows the answer, I would be eternally gratefull for the answer which releases me from this annoying burden.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the URL

> change url: "Test",  to url: "Application Path /CheckForLettersSpacesStripes",

or try another one way by using `PageMethods`

You don't need any lines , just try this code instead of your code

```
PageMethods.CheckForLettersSpacesStripes(input);
```

[referred from](http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx)

Comment: I tried that before, the pagemethods returns undefined and the right url(I'm sorry I didn't place the right one, I tested something the last time) also returns an undefined. Whilst in both cases I console log the input values, which show correctly.